# Get form field names with javascript or php?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms, field

Is there a way to return a list / array of all the field names that are contained within a form? I.e if i made a form with 10 fields ('name', 'email' etc...) on submit i can determine what the element names are?

Comment: your problem could be solved in php and javascript... would be nice to know which one you prefer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript we can get the `name` attribute of each form element like this:

```
$('form').on('submit', function () {
    var names = [];
    $.each($(this).find('input, textarea'), function () {
        names.push(this.name);
    });
});
```

This gathers the `name` attribute of each `input` or `textarea` element in the form and puts them in an array, `names`.

Note that `.on()` is new as of jQuery 1.7 and in this case is the same as using `.bind()`: http://api.jquery.com/on

In PHP you can loop through each of the `$_GET` or `$_POST` variables:

```
<?php
$names = array();
if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) {
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
        //$key is the name you wanted, and $val is the value of that input
        $names[] = $key;
    }
}
?>
```

And again, the `$names` variable is an array of all the names of form elements.

## Update

If you want to create an associative array of `names` : `values` in JS you can do this:

```
$('form').on('submit', function () {
    var names = {};
    $.each($(this).find('input, textarea'), function () {
        names[this.name] = this.value;
    });
});
```

Now you can access the `names` variable like this:

```
alert(names.email);//this will alert the value of the input who's name is `email`
```

Comment: Works brilliant. When i try and access [0] in the array. it prints the name twice?

Comment: Ok, so how would i go about putting each one into a variable?

Comment: @ChrisTill Here's a demo showing how to use this: http://jsfiddle.net/d8UnZ/. You'll notice only the first index is alerted, and if you watch your console then you will see the whole array.

Comment: @ChrisTill If you want to create an associative array of `names` : `values` then try my **update**.

Comment: Ah Thanks, that works well. I need to get the names[1] etc into a php variable. Any suggestions?

Comment: @ChrisTill If you need it in PHP, then use the PHP example I posted (or one that someone else posted in response to your question). You'll be doing extra work on the client-side for no reason if you gather the names and then pass them along with the form submission... just get the names from the `$_POST` or `$_GET` array in your PHP.

Comment: @Jasper I am using this method to get all element names, however, some of the element which created instantly in the webpage cannot be searched in this method.
Any idea to solve it?

Comment: @user3423149 the JS will run when the form is submitted and searches for inputs that are within the form. Therefore if you're dynamically creating more inputs they should be found as long as they are being created before the `submit` event is fired, are being created within the form in question, and they are either `input` or `textarea` tag types (since that's what the selector looks for).

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript

The raw JS way to do that is:

```
const inputs = document['<your form name>'].getElementsByTagName("input");
for (const input in inputs) {
    if (inputs[input] && inputs[input].name) {
       console.log(inputs[input].name);
    }
}
```

### PHP

Yes. They are all in the superglobals `$_GET` (for all of the GET variables), `$_POST` (if your form has `method="POST"`), and `$_REQUEST` (`$_REQUEST` is, by default Environment, Get, Post, Cookie, and Server (in that order) [you can read more here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order)).

If you want to just get the *names*, then you can use `array_keys` on any of the above.

Comment: With the caveat that `$_REQUEST` combines `$_GET`, `$_POST`, and `$_COOKIE` so it's possible for values from the form to be overwritten by values in one of the other two.

Comment: In js approach, what if when fields are radio, textarea or select type?

Comment: @Shiplu Radio are just `input` tags. Use `getElementsByTagName("select");` etc. for the rest.

Comment: You set the list data to `inputs` var but then later referenced it with `lst` var. I edited and fixed. Also I used the code as I could only find other answers using the form's ID (which one doesn't always have). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are the keys of your $_POST e.g:

```
$_POST['name'] = 'whatever name was in the form';
```

You can do a `print_r($_POST)` to see all keys.

(or `$_GET` depending on your forms submit method)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery serialize:
http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  alert($(this).serialize());
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the `$_POST` array contains all the field that have been submitted if the form's method was post.  If the method was get then `$_GET` has the form fields (as well as any other get params that happen to be in the URL)

Answer (score 0):

With JQuery you can know it by selecting the input elements and using `attr('name');`

With PHP :

you can traverse `$_GET`, `$_POST` with foreach
You can also get the list of keys by using `array_keys($_POST)`;

Answer (score 0):

`:input` selector will find form elements in client

http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/

demo  http://jsfiddle.net/JBsbL/

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    var inputList = [];
    $(this).find(':input').each(function() {
        inputList.push(this.name);
    })
    alert(inputList.join(',  '))
    return false;
})​
```

Answer (score 0):

These solutions fully solve your problem, but they wroted as use jQuery. jQuery is not a populer library nowadays. We can solve with pure JavaScript more easily.

```
[...document.querySelectorAll("form input, form textarea, form select")].map(el => el.name)
```